# Can we use state variables in Flink's trigger?

Tags: triggers, state, apache-flink, flink-streaming, sliding-window

I am using Apache Flink's sliding window with trigger. I would like to use a state variable in the trigger. However, I did not find any **rich** function corresponding to trigger function.

```
inputStream.keyBy(new KeySelector<Integer, String>() {
            @Override
            public String getKey(Integer i) throws Exception {
                return i;
            }
        }).window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(windowSize), Time.seconds(slideStep)))
            .trigger(new Trigger<String, TimeWindow> {
    

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(String str, long l, TimeWindow timeWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {            
            return TriggerResult.CONTINUE; 
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long l, TimeWindow timeWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
        return TriggerResult.FIRE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onEventTime(long l, TimeWindow timeWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
        return TriggerResult.FIRE;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(TimeWindow timeWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {

    })
            .apply(new RichWindowFunction<String, String, String, TimeWindow>() {...}
```

So my question is, can we use state variables inside trigger block?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Triggers can be stateful. Look at [CountTrigger](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.12/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/triggers/CountTrigger.java) for an example. You'll see that it keeps a count of how many elements have been added to the window in

```java
private final ReducingStateDescriptor<Long> stateDesc =
        new ReducingStateDescriptor<>("count", new Sum(), LongSerializer.INSTANCE);
```

It then uses that state in its `onElement` method

```java
public TriggerResult onElement(Object element, long timestamp, W window, TriggerContext ctx)
            throws Exception {
    ReducingState<Long> count = ctx.getPartitionedState(stateDesc);
    count.add(1L);
    if (count.get() >= maxCount) {
        count.clear();
        return TriggerResult.FIRE;
    }
    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
}
```

and clears it in its `clear` method

```java
public void clear(W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    ctx.getPartitionedState(stateDesc).clear();
}
```

Keep in mind that if you are implementing a mergeable window type, then your Trigger will have to use state that can be merged, and then merge it when windows are merged. (Since you are using some flavor of sliding window, you can probably ignore this.)

Comment: I found that as the window slides, the states are reset. I would like to retain the keyed state values between window slides. Is it possible? I also tried removing "ctx.getPartitionedState(stateDesc).clear();" from the clear method, but it doesn't work. 
I am using ValueState.

Comment: The only state that can be retained from one window to another is `ProcessWindowFunction.Context#globalState`.

Comment: what does TriggerContext.getPartitionedState mean? Is that mean this state works on current partition(or current map stage)?

Comment: It means that the state is key-partitioned (it follows the current keyBy).